# Array sum in C shows different output

Tags: c, arrays

I am learning about arrays C with some example. I am having a strange situation where my code produces different output for each time with same input.

```
int main(){
    int arr[6][6];
    arr[0][0]=1;
    arr[0][1]=1;
    arr[0][2]=1;
    arr[0][3]=0;
    arr[0][4]=0;
    arr[0][5]=0;

    arr[1][0]=0;
    arr[1][1]=1;
    arr[1][2]=0;
    arr[1][3]=0;
    arr[1][4]=0;
    arr[1][5]=0;

    arr[2][0]=1;
    arr[2][1]=1;
    arr[2][2]=1;
    arr[2][3]=0;
    arr[2][4]=0;
    arr[2][5]=0;

    arr[3][0]=0;
    arr[3][1]=9;
    arr[3][2]=2;
    arr[3][3]=-4;
    arr[3][4]=-4;
    arr[3][5]=0;

    arr[4][0]=0;
    arr[4][1]=0;
    arr[4][2]=0;
    arr[4][3]=-2;
    arr[4][4]=0;
    arr[4][5]=0;

    arr[5][0]=0;
    arr[5][1]=0;
    arr[5][2]=-1;
    arr[5][3]=-2;
    arr[5][4]=-4;
    arr[5][5]=0;
    int tmpSum=0;
    int sum=0;
    for(int arr_i = 0; arr_i < 6; arr_i++){
       for(int arr_j = 0; arr_j < 4; arr_j++){

          if(arr[arr_i][arr_j]!=0 && arr[arr_i][arr_j+2]!=0){
              tmpSum=0;
              tmpSum+=arr[arr_i][arr_j]+arr[arr_i+1][arr_j]+arr[arr_i+2][arr_j];
              tmpSum+=arr[arr_i+1][arr_j+1];
              tmpSum+=arr[arr_i][arr_j+2]+arr[arr_i+1][arr_j+2]+arr[arr_i+2][arr_j+2];
              if(tmpSum>sum){
                  sum=tmpSum;
              }
          }
       }
    }
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

My output  differs as bellow:

```
sh-4.3$ main                                                                                                                                                                                                  
1596448349                                                                                                                                                                                                    
sh-4.3$ main                                                                                                                                                                                                  
1608309885                                                                                                                                                                                                    
sh-4.3$ main                                                                                                                                                                                                  
13
```

My expected output is 13 always
Sorry if this question is too basic.

Comment: You may have accessed out-of-range. Let me check...

Comment: Yes, out-of-range access that invokes *undefined behavior* will happen. https://ideone.com/pIwWdE

Comment: if so it should return the random numbers always. why it gives the right answer sometimes while input is static

Comment: Anything may happen when *undefined behavior* is invoked. It seems "the random numbers" happened to include "the right answer".

Comment: It shows..out-of-range access!!! arr_i = 5, arr_j = 2.. but arr[5][2] is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to access values outside of the array here:

```
tmpSum+=arr[arr_i][arr_j]+arr[arr_i+1][arr_j]+arr[arr_i+2][arr_j];
```

When `arr_i` is 5 (the last iteration of the outer loop), `arr_i+2` returns 7, and `arr_i+1` returns 6. The last accessible index of the array is `5`, so this fails.

```
arr[5]: [ 0| 0|-1|-2|-4| 0]123545634234234
```

By accessing `arr[0][6]`, you're going outside the array and just reading random memory, which will result in undefined behaviour. In this case, the undefined behaviour exhibits as a random result.

The same applies to the other two attempts to add to `tmpSum`.

Comment: `arr[0][6]` will happen to be `arr[1][0]` in typical environment. `arr[6][0]` will be physically out-of-range and may be some random value.

Comment: @MikeCAT - Realistically, yeah. Poor example on my part. I'll change it.

Comment: I got it but why sometimes it is working fine? is that a random nature of C?

Comment: @DharanBro - Undefined behaviour is undefined by it's very nature, you can't predict what will happen. Sometimes the random memory you read may contain zeroes, which would mean that a consistent result is returned. Other times it may contain 03948092384 or 4385798, which would result in a random answer.

Comment: changed `for(int arr_i = 0; arr_i < 6; arr_i++)` to `for(int arr_i = 0; arr_i < 4; arr_i++)`